# How can I change the node size in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have made a graph. Now I am facing a problem when I want to change the node size.

When I used `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=times_list, node_color='Gray', node_shape='o')` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y
```

I can understand pos size and times_list size are not the same but I am unable to resolve my problem.

***Code:***

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
fig = plt.subplots(figsize =(32,24))
G.add_edges_from(number_list)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)
edge_labels = duration_list

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=dict(zip(map(tuple,number_list), edge_labels)))
G.size(500)
```

How can I change the size of the nodes?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I can't paste this into an editor and run it

Comment: what is number_list?

Comment: Please again have a look.

Comment: You give 36 nodes and 43 edges. So, there should be 36 node_sizes, not 43. (The nodes are the circles in the graph, the edges are the connecting lines). `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=times_list[:len(pos)])` would work, but probably is not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=times_list[:len(pos)], node_color='Gray', node_shape='o')
```

The problem you have is that `pos` has less entries than `times_list`, therefore you have more labels than nodes, which causes your issue. By taking only the first len(pos) entries from times_list you can resolve your problem.